# Linux: Changing Permissions – No space left on device

Tags: permissions, mount, opensuse, fstab, chmod

I have an external drive. When I just plug the drive into the PC, with a default `/etc/fstab` file, the OS just detects it and it's there in the Dolphin browser. I can select it, I can navigate to it on the command line, read/write/etc the files on it, etc.

I'm trying to mount the drive into my home directory
so that Plex Media Server can access it. I've done this a million times before with this same drive no problem, on Linux.

I recently re-installed the OS and went to set up the drive, same as always. Again, this exact same configuration has worked in the past, on the same version of Linux (OpenSUSE Leap 42.1), on the same machine, with the same hard drive. I've added this entry

```
UUID=F474B7AA74B76DCC /home/craig/MediaDrive ntfs-3g defaults,nofail,permissions,auto 0 1
```

to `/etc/fstab` to mount the drive in my home directory.
I get it mounted to `/home/craig/MediaDrive`.
The first weird thing is that `ls -l` shows

```
d--------- 1 root  root   12288 May 16 18:33 MediaDrive
```

So then I go to set ownership and change permissions with

```
sudo chown -R 777 /home/craig/MediaDrive
```

and I get the error:

```
chmod: changing permissions of ‘MediaDrive’: No space left on device
```

The thing is, there's plenty of space left. There's over 300GB of space left. I'm pasting my `df -h` output below.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sde1       1.9T  1.6T  316G  84% /home/craig/MediaDrive
```

It doesn't seem to be an inode issue; here is the output of `df -i`:

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed      IFree  IUse%  Mounted on
/dev/sde1    331060948   4846  331056102     1%  /home/craig/MediaDrive
```

Again, this permissions issue only exists with the drive when I try to mount it in that location (in my home directory); otherwise when it's just at the default run/media/craig/My Passport location, it's fine. Reads, writes, etc.

How can I get my drive to mount successfully in my home directory?

Comment: It might help if you show the exact `chmod` command that you're using.  Also, you talk about two different ways of mounting your drive; please describe this.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I added the information you asked for. Thanks.

Comment: can you give full `df -lh` output including OS partitions not just your mounted disk? (yes, update your question)

Comment: @user2223059: I put your question into a blender and put the pieces back together in what seems to me to be a more sequential narrative.  Please check it and fix any errors that I made.  And now, I’m afraid that I probably won’t be able to help you any further; I’m stumped.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Honestly, I'm at the point where if no one comes up with anything, after work tomorrow I'm going to just wipe and reinstall from scratch. Maybe there's something weird and random that got screwed up at some point? who knows.

Comment: Did you try to mount the disk in both locations manually (using `mount`, not `/etc/fstab`)? What are the permissions of both locations _before_ you mount?

Comment: I'm not at my home computer, but they're pretty normal looking. I'll add more on that later when I have a chance, but it looks like you would expect a directory's permissions to look.

Comment: Didn't you say that it mounted just fine when you just plugged it in? If so, you don't need to wipe it. Just figure out what options the OS is using to mount it. Maybe the mount options have changed? What is the output of "sudo mount -v"?

Answer (score 1):

Umount it, and make the mountpoint more permissive. Sometimes this is relevant... maybe it is in your case because using a different mountpoint has different results. Compare the permissions on those 2 directories for more info.

Check `man ntfs-3g` for options, and use them, for example:

```
mount -o fmask=664,dmask=775,uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sde1 /home/craig/MediaDrive
```